# How to remove personal data from Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, nintendo-eshop

I've got a Wii U that I never use. It's mere presence taunts me by reminding me of my poor purchasing decisions. If I want to remove all my personal details from it including save games and eShop details before I sell it, do I need to do anything apart from formatting it via the System menu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. That's it. Just do the system reset. [Here are the instructions](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1723/~/how-to-delete-all-content-%26-settings-%28format%29)

1. From the Wii U Menu, select "System Settings."
2. Using the Left Stick, scroll to the "Delete All Content & Settings" and press the A Button.
3. Please read the information displayed on your TV screen, and then tap "Next."
4. Wait for a few seconds, and then tap "Delete Everything."

But there is a [caveat](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1466/).

**What Is Lost after Formatting the System Memory?**

All software data, save data, user information, and other information saved to the console will be deleted.

Data (such as software or save data) saved to USB storage media or SD Cards will no longer be usable.

Deleting all content and settings will not revert the system software to a previous version.

Wii Shop Channel account activity and Wii Points will not be deleted. Even after deleting all content and settings, you will be able to redownload previously purchased software free of charge.

Be aware that you will not be able to redownload any games that are no longer available for purchase or download.

Any linked Nintendo Network IDs will not be deleted when deleting users. The Nintendo Network IDs that were being used before deleting all content and settings can be reused by linking them to new Wii U users.

- Any Nintendo Network IDs that were linked to Wii U users on the
  console cannot be used on other Wii U consoles.
- Your Nintendo eShop purchase history and balance are saved to your
  Nintendo Network ID. If you link an ID you were using with Nintendo
  eShop to a new user after deleting all content and settings, you will
  be able to redownload your purchased software free of charge.
- Pre-installed titles will remain available to redownload on the
  system without the need to re-link an NNID.